# json_decode syntax error 4 from valid json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

### **UPDATE: FINAL SOLUTION**

It turned out to be invisible characters afterall. Which characters exactly? I couldn't tell you.

Here is a 1-liner that fixed the problem:

```
<?php
// get string from $_POST, 
// wp_unslash it, 
// then sanitize as text, 
// then json_decode, 
// and assign to variable as assoc. array ready for action
$location = json_decode(sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3'])), true);

// These are the default sanitization functions used when update_post_meta is fired. 
// By default they:
//   * Check for invalid UTF-8 (uses wp_check_invalid_utf8())
//   * Converts single < characters to entity
//   * Strips all tags
//   * Remove line breaks, tabs and extra white space
//   * Strip octets
?>
```

One or more of those things was causing the issue. It didn't seem like I needed to strip any invisible/special chars, but turns out I did.

NOTE:
None of these had any effect. The built-in WP functions above finally did the trick!

```
<?php
trim($_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3'])

urlencode($_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3'])

str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3']);
?>
```

### **UPDATE**

To get right to the issue at hand, it seems json_decode is not working when I pass it the $location string variable (with $_POST as the source), but works fine using the string itself (which validates fine on https://jsonlint.com and as @CBroe posted at https://3v4l.org/FSDnf)

```
<?php 

global $_POST;

$location = $_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3'];

// var type
echo gettype($location); 
// returns: string

// var_dump
var_dump($location); 
// returns: string(375) "{"lat":27.884301199999999,"lng":-82.389221199999994,"zoom":14,"markers":[{"label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","lat":27.884189800000001,"lng":-82.389353099999994}],"address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],"version":"1.3.2"}"

// echo string
echo $location; 
// returns: {"lat":27.884301199999999,"lng":-82.389221199999994,"zoom":14,"markers":[{"label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","lat":27.884189800000001,"lng":-82.389353099999994}],"address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],"version":"1.3.2"} 

// json_decode string as a variable
var_dump(json_decode($location, true), json_last_error());
// fails with error 4 for syntax

// json_decode string itself
var_dump(json_decode('{"lat":27.884301199999999,"lng":-82.389221199999994,"zoom":14,"markers":[{"label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","lat":27.884189800000001,"lng":-82.389353099999994}],"address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],"version":"1.3.2"}', true), json_last_error());
// works fine

?>
```

Something about the $_POST data source/type because setting the string manually works fine:

```
// set string variable
$location = '{"lat":27.884301199999999,"lng":-82.389221199999994,"zoom":14,"markers":[{"label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","lat":27.884189800000001,"lng":-82.389353099999994}],"address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],"version":"1.3.2"}';

//  var_dump json_decode
var_dump(json_decode($location, true), json_last_error()); 
// works fine
```

I'm not sure where "the break" exists. From everything I can see this should work fine, but it doesn't:

```
<?php
global $_POST;

// get string from $_POST, json_decode() it, and then var_dump
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3'], true), json_last_error());
// fails with error 4 for syntax
?>
```

### **ORIGINAL POST BELOW**

Lots of other topics with a similar problem, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have VALID JSON data that I grab from $_POST when a Wordpress custom post_type is added/updated. The purpose is to use some of the JSON data for other specific custom fields on each save. Here is some example JSON data grabbed:

```
{
    "lat":27.884301199999999,
    "lng":-82.389221199999994,
    "zoom":12,
    "markers":[
        {
            "label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States",
            "default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States",
            "lat":27.884189800000001,
            "lng":-82.389353099999994
        }
    ],
    "address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States",
    "layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],
    "version":"1.3.2"
}
```

It validates perfectly fine at https://jsonlint.com

When I try decode it, json_last_error() shows "4" for "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX". The relevant code in my function looks like this:

```
<?php
    global $_POST;
        
    // get JSON data from $_POST
    $location = $_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3']

    /* Example JSON data for "$location" is shown above */
      
    // get assoc. array from JSON
    $location_decode = json_decode( $location, true );
     
    /* here's where my custom code would go to do all of my processing */
     
    // add/update values to post_meta table after all processing
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'JSON_Decoded', $location_decode );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'JSON_Last_error', json_last_error() );
?>
```

"$location_decode" is always empty (which means the 'JSON_Decoded' meta field is also always empty).

**var_dump of $location**

```
string(375) "{"lat":27.884301199999999,"lng":-82.389221199999994,"zoom":14,"markers":[{"label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","lat":27.884189800000001,"lng":-82.389353099999994}],"address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],"version":"1.3.2"}"
```

**Solutions Tried:**

I tried removing some of the invisible special characters like BOM, but since the source of the data is $_POST and not a file, these kind of invisible characters shouldn't really matter:

```
<?php
    if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($location), 'efbbbf')) {
        $location = substr($location, 3);
    }
?>
```

I tried setting encoding to UTF8 prior to JSON decode, even though the UTF8 is the default encoding for the site and DB. 2 methods tried, and both had no effect:

```
<?php
    // method #1
    $location = utf8_encode($_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3']);

    // method #2
    $location = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3'], "UTF-8", "UTF-8"); 
?>
```

I've been messing with it for hours and now I'm reaching out for help out of frustration.

What is wrong with the sample JSON data syntax and/or how can I get it to pass JSON_decode's syntax checks?

Comment: Any chance that the content of "$_POST['acf']['field_621fa9e5511f3']" is not not transferred as JSON and instead already is an object? If so, json_decode won't work.

Comment: Give us a sample of `var_dump($location)` please.

Comment: @dominikjosch - var_dump shows as a string. But, your comment gave me an idea to try. The JSON data is a specific sub-field within the overall ACF (advanced custom fields) JSON data. Perhaps I can try to json_decode the WHOLE thing first, then just grab the specific sub-field. Will give it try and see if that works.

Comment: @deceze - var_dump added

Comment: The length reported in the var_dump output appears to exactly match the number of characters, and there is nothing that would require more than one byte in UTF-8 - so there should not be any additional BOM or whatever to begin with. The exact thing you have shown us decodes fine and without any errors, https://3v4l.org/FSDnf Really rather unclear what your problem is supposed to be here, with the information given so far.

Comment: @CBroe - wasn't sure of the exact issue myself, but narrowed it down and posted an update.

Comment: What does `var_dump($location == '{"lat":27.884301199999999,"lng":-82.389221199999994,"zoom":14,"markers":[{"label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","default_label":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","lat":27.884189800000001,"lng":-82.389353099999994}],"address":"Burts Road 6311, 33619 Tampa, Florida United States","layers":["OpenStreetMap.Mapnik"],"version":"1.3.2"}'); ` return?

Comment: A useful thing to find possibly hidden garbage characters is `echo urlencode($location)`…

Comment: comment deleted for now. going to try comparisons as suggested by @CBroe more thoroughly first.

Comment: Topic solved. Solution posted above. Thank you dominikjosch, deceze, & CBroe for your probing. It led to the solution.

Comment: Don't post your answer in your question. If you found your own solution, then post it as an actual and accept it. Otherwise delete the question.

Comment: gotcha @j08691. New here and figuring it out as I go. Topic is currently closed. Will adjust if/when it's open for solutions. Solution may be helpful to anyone struggling with JSON data while adding/editing posts in wp_admin.